# Texture is mirrored on some sides

Tags: gltf

I want to display multiple boxes within a 3D scene.

I take the BoxTextured.gltf sample (https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/blob/master/2.0/BoxTextured/glTF-Embedded/BoxTextured.gltf) as template for my gltf file and only create  new nodes, meshes , materials, textures and images image for each box.

Displaying (and positioning) of the boxes already works.

The next step is to put some additional information on each box.

My problem is that some sides are actually mirrored. (You don't see that at first glance with the sample bitmap, but you see it when you replace the sample with text)

Is there a simple way to correct that?
Is tehre an easy way to display different information on each side of the boxes?

Comment: This question needs more information — the glTF file format can be loaded in various viewers and engines, or edited in 3D modeling tools like Blender or Maya. Without knowing which of these tools you're trying to use, the question cannot be answered.

Comment: I am currently using the Babylon IS viewer. I modify the glTF with a custom (and very simple)  Python program. I do some testing with a simple text editor. The problem also happens in the unmodified file (you just don't see at first glance)

Comment: The way that images map onto a 3D model is controlled by UV coordinates. If you aren't familiar with those, I'd strongly recommend opening the glTF file in a 3D tool like Blender, rather than trying to edit the file directly.